# Is there a macro to conditionally copy rows to another worksheet?

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2003, worksheet, vba

Is there a macro or a way to conditionally copy rows from one worksheet to another in Excel 2003?

I'm pulling a list of data from SharePoint via a web query into a blank worksheet in Excel, and then I want to copy the rows for a particular month to a particular worksheet (for example, all July data from a SharePoint worksheet to the Jul worksheet, all June data from a SharePoint worksheet to Jun worksheet, etc.).

**Sample data**

```
Date - Project - ID - Engineer
8/2/08 - XYZ - T0908-5555 - JS
9/4/08 - ABC - T0908-6666 - DF
9/5/08 - ZZZ - T0908-7777 - TS
```

It's not a one-off exercise. I'm trying to put together a dashboard that my boss can pull the latest data from SharePoint and see the monthly results, so it needs to be able to do it all the time and organize it cleanly.

Answer (score 5):

This works: The way it's set up I called it from the immediate pane, but you can easily create a sub() that will call MoveData once for each month, then just invoke the sub.

You may want to add logic to sort your monthly data after it's all been copied

```
Public Sub MoveData(MonthNumber As Integer, SheetName As String)

Dim sharePoint As Worksheet
Dim Month As Worksheet
Dim spRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set sharePoint = Sheets("Sharepoint")
Set Month = Sheets(SheetName)
Set spRange = sharePoint.Range("A2")
Set spRange = sharePoint.Range("A2:" & spRange.End(xlDown).Address)
For Each cell In spRange
    If Format(cell.Value, "MM") = MonthNumber Then
        copyRowTo sharePoint.Range(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row), Month
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Sub copyRowTo(rng As Range, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim newRange As Range
    Set newRange = ws.Range("A1")
    If newRange.Offset(1).Value <> "" Then
        Set newRange = newRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
        Else
        Set newRange = newRange.Offset(1)
    End If
    rng.Copy
    newRange.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that uses some of VBA's built in date functions and stores all the date data in an array for comparison, which may give better performance if you get a lot of data:

```
Public Sub MoveData(MonthNum As Integer, FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet As Worksheet)
    Const DateCol = "A" 'column where dates are store
    Const DestCol = "A" 'destination column where dates are stored. We use this column to find the last populated row in ToSheet
    Const FirstRow = 2 'first row where date data is stored
    'Copy range of values to Dates array
    Dates = FromSheet.Range(DateCol & CStr(FirstRow) & ":" & DateCol & CStr(FromSheet.Range(DateCol & CStr(FromSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row)).Value
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(Dates) To UBound(Dates)
        If IsDate(Dates(i, 1)) Then
            If Month(CDate(Dates(i, 1))) = MonthNum Then
                Dim CurrRow As Long
                'get the current row number in the worksheet
                CurrRow = FirstRow + i - 1
                Dim DestRow As Long
                'get the destination row
                DestRow = ToSheet.Range(DestCol & CStr(ToSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                'copy row CurrRow in FromSheet to row DestRow in ToSheet
                FromSheet.Range(CStr(CurrRow) & ":" & CStr(CurrRow)).Copy ToSheet.Range(DestCol & CStr(DestRow))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is partially pseudocode, but you will want something like:

```
rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
n = 0

while n <= rows
  if ActiveSheet.Rows(n).Cells(DateColumnOrdinal).Value > '8/1/08' AND < '8/30/08' then
     ActiveSheet.Rows(n).CopyTo(DestinationSheet)
  endif
  n = n + 1
wend
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this manually is:

- Use Data - AutoFilter
- Apply a custom filter based on a date range
- Copy the filtered data to the relevant month sheet
- Repeat for every month

Listed below is code to do this process via VBA.

It has the advantage of handling monthly sections of data rather than individual rows.  Which can result in quicker processing for larger sets of data.

```
    Sub SeperateData()

    Dim vMonthText As Variant
    Dim ExcelLastCell As Range
    Dim intMonth As Integer

   vMonthText = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", _
 "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sharepoint").Select
        Range("A1").Select

    RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sharepoint").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Forces excel to determine the last cell, Usually only done on save
    Set ExcelLastCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sharepoint"). _
     Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
'Determines the last cell with data in it


        Selection.EntireColumn.Insert
        Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Month No."
        Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(RC[1])"
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A3:A" & ExcelLastCell.Row).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Calculate
    'Insert a helper column to determine the month number for the date

        For intMonth = 1 To 12
            Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & intMonth
            Selection.Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("" & vMonthText(intMonth - 1)).Select
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Cells.Select
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            Range("A1").Select
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sharepoint").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next intMonth
    'Filter the data to a particular month
    'Convert the month number to text
    'Copy the filtered data to the month sheet
    'Delete the helper column
    'Repeat for each month

        Selection.AutoFilter
        Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
 'Get rid of the auto-filter and delete the helper column

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is just a one-off exercise, as an easier alternative, you could apply filters to your source data, and then copy and paste the filtered rows into your new worksheet?