# Excel - Macro to compare multiple rows then copy to different worksheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to figure out a Macro to copy a row of data to a new worksheet once my conditions are meet.  I found another question answer but it is too different for me to figure it out: [Other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84331/excel-macro-to-conditionally-copy-rows-to-another-worksheet)

What I have is a 30000+ row and BB columns of data.  I want to compare data in one column from row to row and when I find the sequence I want copy the last row in the sequence to a different worksheet.  Sample Data:

Numbers - Other Data - Other Data... 
   1    -    xxx     -     xxx
   0    -    xxx     -     xxx
   1    -    xxx     -     xxx
   1    -    xxx     -     xxx
   0    -    xxx     -     xxx
   1    -    xxx     -     xxx
   1    -    xxx     -     xxx
   1    -    yyy     -     yyy
   0    -    xxx     -     xxx

In this case, I would want to find the sequence of three ones and copy the row with yyy data into a new worksheet.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub thirdmatch()

Dim arrKey() As Variant
Dim arrOut() As Variant
Dim rowCnt As Integer
Dim rr As Integer
Dim rOut As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range

Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set r1 = s1.Range("A2", s1.Range("A4"))
Set r2 = s2.Range("A2")

rowCnt = s1.Range("A1", s1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
rr = 0
rOut = 0

Do While rr < rowCnt
    arrKey = r1.Offset(rr, 0)
    If arrKey(1, 1) = arrKey(2, 1) And arrKey(2, 1) = arrKey(3, 1) And arrKey(1, 1) = 1 Then
        arrOut = s1.Range("A" & rr + 4, s1.Range("BB" & rr + 4))
        For i = 1 To 54
            r2.Offset(rOut, i - 1) = arrOut(1, i)
        Next i
        rOut = rOut + 1
    End If
    rr = rr + 1
Loop

End Sub
```